# Where can we use Point Coordinate system in Metal

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

I have doubt that cannot we use point_coord in a Fragment Shader where we are drawing a Quad.

If it is only used with point can we use Texture with point in Fragment shader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct. As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf) says, a parameter attributed with `point_coord` contains "two-dimensional coordinates, which range from 0.0 to 1.0 across a **point primitive**, specifying the location of the current fragment within the point primitive."

If you need similar parameters inside a quad, the easiest way is to include a pair of coordinates in the struct you return from your vertex function, which will then be interpolated in a perspective-correct manner across the surface of your quad.

You can either generate these coordinates based on the vertex ID in your vertex function, or generate them in advance in your host code and pass them in in a vertex buffer.